# How can I play 16th-note hi-hats at 150 bpm?

Tags: technique, drum-kits

Is it possible to play a beat of 16th-note hi-hats with bass drum on 1 and 3, and snare on 2 and 4, at 150 bpm? I.e.:

```
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|----s-------s---|
|d-------d-------|
```

A song I'm trying to learn seems to require this (although this may be a bug in its transcription).

It seems very doable if you skip the hi-hat on counts 2 and 4, but I'm wondering if it's possible to hit the hi-hat too.

Are single-handed 16th-notes at 150 bpm possible? If not, would you use some doubles (and if so, can you give an example as to which hand to play on the hi-hat and which on the snare)? Maybe some foot tricks?

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid transcription questions aren't [on topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, though the technique aspects are. Please edit to focus on those!

Comment: @AndyBonner thank you, I've removed all transcription questions.

Comment: I'll leave it to actual drummers to answer, but I'll bet the answer is you're simply supposed to leave out the hi hat on the snare notes...

Comment: it might also be that the song in question was programmed with a drum machine or DAW.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's a sequencer in the original song we pretend to not have heard, and playing it on a real drum kit will always sound different. So what is the point? (I'd play RLRLLLRL on hi-hat if I for some reason had to play it as exact as possible but it would not sound the same)

Comment: @ojs - on first hearing I thought electronic drumkit but you're probably right. On a sequencer, do what you like...

Comment: It's *possible* to hit the hi-hat too. But that's not how you play Sunday Bloody Sunday, nor do you do it with one hand. Which is basically the one situation (doing doubles on the HH) where it *is* ok to not hit the HH on the snare... *and* you're not supposed to.

Comment: Just don't pay any attention to me but I would say, with drum sticks :D sorry, I'll be good now I promise.

Comment: John Bonham would just use the foot pedal to play the hi-hats, I think it's possible at that speed but might take a while to achieve. It's a great technique, frees up your hands. It's a bit extreme but just thought I'd mention it

Comment: It seems the song in question has been edited out, I think it would be beneficial to keep it in the question body, especially as some answers appear to reference it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @Tim, the standard way a drummer would handle this is alternate sticking and leaving out the high hat on 2 and 4. However if you really want to have that simultaneous hat and snare it’s not out of the question. Assuming you’re starting with the right hand you can do this: (B is for both hands)

RLRL BLRL RLRL BLRL

It requires 3 rapid strokes in a row with the left hand. It’s not easy but also not impossible for a skilled drummer by any means. It’s not necessary to do it this way unless you literally want every 16th on the hi hit played. It’s certainly easier than trying to play steady 16ths with one hand at 150bpm.

Comment: Something like a paradiddle. Which I struggle with...

Comment: @Tim I thought of that but it’s really not. Paradiddles are symmetrical but this requires more work with one hand than the other.

Comment: Hence 'something like' - but not the same, probably worse!

Comment: Push-pull aka Moeller technique

Comment: @Tim You’re right, probably worse, check out Dave Garibaldi using variations on paradiddles in his drum kit groove playing: https://youtu.be/JIemsK_0lXc?si=PunFt7ELLXUaNEUl&t=300

Comment: It can also be achieved using a sort of "mixed" paradiddle, which allows avoiding the triple stroke, for example (for right handed drummers): LRLR BLRL LRLR BLRL. In this way, the right hand can play the snare right after the hat, which is easier due to the hand/drum position, and the left can play the double *doubles* while remaining on the hat.

Comment: @musicamante I like it. I probably can’t play it but I like it! ;)

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy You already know: it's just a matter of practice ;-) Do it while watching pointless tv show, commuting, in the elevator/lift, while waiting for the green light, etc. A couple of weeks like this, and your neurons will be ready for it :-D

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr** summary: I am not convinced that 4th 16th note on the backbeat is actually in the original song, but even if it is, those drums are programmed and not (meant to be) played by a human, and at any rate, the live drummer does not play that note.

---

Carpenter Brut is a one-man electro project. Carpenter Brut is a keyboard player, not a drummer, these parts are definitely not recorded, they are programmed.

It is very hard to hear whether the hi-hat on the downbeat is actually played or not. But even if it is: it is fairly typical for non-drummers to program drum parts in a way that they cannot actually be played by a drummer. Nor would anyone expect an electronic drum part to be playable by a human player.

I just looked at a live concert as well, and the drummer is definitely playing a standard disco beat during that part:

```
X: 1
T: Turbo Killer [B part]
C: Carpenter Brut
O: France
M: 4/4
L: 1/16
Q: 1/4=150
Z: Jörg W Mittag
R: disco feel
%%score (Hands Feet)
V: Hands stem=up
V: Feet stem=down
K:C clef=perc
%%ornament above
[V:Hands]|:"^R"g"^L"g"^R"L!open!g"^L"g "^R"c"^L"g"^R"L!open!g"^L"g "^R"g"^L"g"^R"L!open!g"^L"g "^R"c"^L"g"^R"L!open!g"^L"g:|
[V:Feet]|:F4F4F4F4:|
```

The live instruments are also heavily augmented with backing tracks, so even on a live performance, not everything you hear is actually played.

Even without hearing the live performance, I would have played this part like a disco part, and I am convinced that is what the live drummer is actually playing.

Comment: Here's the recording, for reference: https://youtu.be/i6U8Nki1G8Q?feature=shared&t=3610

Comment: what the beep is disco feel?

Comment: @yarns that notation means "emulate what other disco players do for anything that isn't written down" - like when to play notes outside/around a strict metronomic beat, and what notes to emphasize. In other words, create a disco "groove."

Comment: very interesting @crass_sandwich

Answer (score 4):

This seems to me like a typical 'disco' beat. There's absolutely no need to play snare and hi-hat together on beats 2 and 4, so alternate hands, leaving the actual beats 2 and 4 themselves to be played, for r.h. drummers, with the r.h. on snare.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a relative intermediate so I'll give an example from one of the best drummers I know, Takashi Sasaki of Casiopea.

タイム・リミット (Time Limit) is one of their more popular songs and it starts with a 4/4 16th-note with a relatively similar beat as seen below. Now admittedly, it is a tiny bit slower at 127 bpm but I think that it's a great example of how you can make it sound seamless. The snare is particularly isolated in these notes but if you listen to [the actual track](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PFOkv3a0KY), the missing hi-hat is almost unnoticeable. Also, don't forget that accents can go a long way in selling the beat and making it sound cleaner. So basically what I'm trying to say is, as long as you hit the hi-hat cleanly it won't be noticed, especially in such a fast song. I'll leave the sheet below for reference:

[image: Time Limit - Casiopea (127 bpm) First Measure on Drums]

[The entire sheet from Musescore](https://musescore.com/user/3651386/scores/6821461)

Hope that this was helpful :)